# Create a proper path for navigation

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I have to create a navigation path for ships. All the ships come to a center point and halt there for a while.
The coordinates of the ships and the center point (MotherShip) come from the database.

The code to select the data. The center point is static.

```
<?php
    $sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM ship WHERE id=" . $id . " AND start_date BETWEEN '" . $s_date . "' AND '" . $e_date . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, $sqlqry);
    $locations = array();
    $counter=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($locations, $row);
    }
    $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

The problem is that there are some ships that start from the center point in water. They should start and end at land.

[Like here you can see one ship at the start of red line(land) and one at the start of green line (in water where center point is).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGu5X.png)

Here is my google maps JavaScript part for initialization part.

```
var nrows = <?php echo json_encode($nrows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
    var locMatrix = <?php echo json_encode($locations,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
    var m_ship_rows = <?php echo json_encode($m_ship_rows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
    var m_ship = <?php echo json_encode($m_ship,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;

      var line;
      var line1;
      var lineArray = [];
      var lineArray1 = [];
      var DrivePath = [];
      // This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.

      function initMap() {

        var intervalForAnimation;
        var count = 0;
        var n = 2;
        for(var i=0;i<=nrows-1;i++)
        {
        console.log(DrivePath[i]);
        DrivePath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locMatrix[i][1], locMatrix[i][2]),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(17.8674, 66.543),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(locMatrix[i][3], locMatrix[i][4]));
      }
        var Colors = [
        "#FF0000", 
        "#00FF00", 
        "#0000FF", 
        "#FFFFFF", 
        "#000000", 
        "#FFFF00", 
        "#00FFFF", 
        "#FF00FF"
        ];
```

The entire code is at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tcoL9b3/).

Also you can visit my github repo for the entire code.

http://github.com/Tejas-Nanaware/ship-scheduling-and-animation-tool

Comment: Guys, this is a well-documented question and shows a valid problem. Do not close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found a different solution which partly helped me.

```
// Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
        for(var i=0; i <=nrows; i++)
        {
          var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [{lat: locMatrix[i][1], lng: locMatrix[i][2]},
            {lat: 17.8674, lng: 66.543},
            {lat: locMatrix[i][3], lng: locMatrix[i][4]}],
            icons: [{
              icon: lineSymbol,
              offset: '100%'
          }],
          strokeColor: '#000000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          map: map
      });
          animateCircle(line);
      }
```

animateCircle() Function:

```
function animateCircle(line) {
          var count = 0;
          window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count+0.5) % 200;
            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
        }, 20);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is coming from the fact that you have a left-closed interval for start date. There are surely ships which started their journey from the mother ship after the start date, but in fact, their real start day from land is earlier than your parameterized start date. So, you need to decide what to do with the ships which were already on a journey on your start date, but between that date and this moment they have been on a mother ship as well. If you do not want to display their path, then you need to exclude them. If you want to gather earlier events for those ships, then you will need to run another selection for these specific ships to gather earlier data. In any case you will need a function which will get a starting point of a ship and determine whether it is a mother ship or dry land.

Comment: No Lajos. I displayed the ships whose start date is in between the two selected dates. So if the ship has already started, it is not displayed. Not even in water.

I believe that there is some problem in the way that I am initializing it.
new google.maps.LatLng() helps in creating a line with two points.
whereas, I have to create a path with 3 points.

So I guess when I initialize, it takes that one ship starts from land and ends at mothership, and another ship starts from mother ship and ends at land.

How can I make a path where the ships go from land to central point and land again?

Comment: So you want another leg to be created from the mothership back to land? Is the route from mothership to land different from the 1st leg? I think you'll just need a new leg (polyline for it), but the data on its direction will still come from your database and be plotted.

Comment: @adjuremods The navigation path is consists of two lines that are joint at one point (mother ship) in the sea and other two are at the land. So the navigation path bends at the mother ship. Both the lines are appearing on the map. But the problem is that while initialisation, I have given all the 3 points. That makes a logical error in the path breaking it into 2 different ships one ship starts from land and ends at mother ship, and second one starts from mother ship and ends at land. This should not happen. There should just be one ship that goes through these 3 points start, mother ship, end

Comment: @EnclosedMail, maybe the location of the ship in the two coordinates is not the very same, since it is on the water and will move slightly over time, not to mention GPS inaccuracies. You might want to check for the area instead with a sensibility radius.

Comment: @LajosArpad In my database, I have selected the latitudes from Google maps manually, so it will be accurate. Also start, end and center points will obviously be different! You can see that in the image that I have attached.